# Defining locales for a packaged app provokes "fails to download"

Tags: json, manifest, firefox-os

I'm trying to install a packaged application in Firefox OS simulator.

The installation succeeds only partially, since a link for the app is created, but without the proper icon. When I try to execute it, asks to download the app, which fails with a simple "download failed", and the application doesn't start.

I found the <del>cause</del> *trigger* of the failure, but I don't understand it. By mangling with the manifest I found that the problem lies in the declaration of `locales` in the manifest.

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "name": "xxx",
  "description": "xxx",
  "launch_path": "/app.html",

  "icons": {
    "16":  "/icon_0016px.png",
    "32":  "/icon_0032px.png",
    "48":  "/icon_0048px.png",
    "60":  "/icon_0060px.png",
    "64":  "/icon_0064px.png",
    "128":  "/icon_0128px.png",
    "256":  "/icon_0256px.png",
    "512":  "/icon_0512px.png"
  },
  "developer": {
    "name": "xxx",
    "url": "http://xxx"
  },

  "fullscreen": "true",

  "default_locale": "es",
  "locales": {
    "it": {
      "name": "L'Open Web",
      "description": "Eccitante azione di sviluppo web open!"
    },
    "de": {
      "name": "Der Open Web",
      "description": "Spannende offene Web-Entwicklung-Action!"
    }
  }
}
```

If I remove the `locales` block (and the preceeding comma of course), the application installs correctly, and that block is copypasted from the [Mozilla example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Build/Manifest#locales). The `default_locale` is not overriden either. So, I have no idea.

EDIT----------------

It works if I install it from the WebIde or the Application Manager. However, if I try a install from a webpage using `navigator.mozApps.installPackage` it fails.

I have tried different versions of Firefox (Firefox 30-34, Firefox OS 1.3-2.2) in different platforms (Win, Linux) and with different locales, and a Firefox OS phone (FOS 1.0), with similar results.

The manifest validator always says it's ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the same locales block on an app of mine, and it works. I successfully installed the app on the Firefox OS 1.1 simulator and on my phone, running Firefox OS 1.4. Maybe you are experiencing a bug in your simulator.

You can also try the app validator at https://marketplace.firefox.com/developers/validator.